# Is it possible to use callbacks to access a single trajectory in Julia's DifferentialEquations Ensemble Problems?

Tags: callback, julia, differentialequations.jl

I am new to Julia and trying to use the Julia package DifferentialEquations to simultaneously solve for several conditions of the same set of coupled ODEs. My system is a model of an experiment and in one of the conditions, I increase the amount of one of the dependent variables at mid-way through the process.

I would like to be able to adjust the condition of this single trajectory, however so far I am only able to adjust all the trajectories at once. Is it possible to access a single one using callbacks? If not, is there a better way to do this?

Here is a simplified example using the lorentz equations for what I want to be doing:

```
#Differential Equations setup
function lorentz!(du,u,p,t)
    a,r,b=p
      
    du[1]= a*(u[2]-u[1])             
    du[2]=u[1]*(r-u[3])-u[2]
    du[3]=u[1]*u[2]-b*u[3];      
end

#function to cycle through inital conditions
function prob_func(prob,i,repeat)
    remake(prob; u0 = u0_arr[i]);
end
    
#inputs
t_span=[(0.0,100.0),(0.0,100.0)];
u01=[0.0;1.0;0.0];
u02=[0.0;1.0;0.0];
u0_arr = [u01,u02];
p=[10.,28.,8/3];

#initialising the Ensemble Problem
prob = ODEProblem(lorentz!,u0_arr[1],t_span[1],p);
CombinedProblem = EnsembleProblem(prob,
                                    prob_func = prob_func, #-> (prob),#repeat is a count for how many times the trajectories had been repeated
                                    safetycopy = true # determines whether a safetly deepcopy is called on the prob before the prob_func (sounds best to leave as true for user-given prob_func)
                                    );
    
#introducing callback 
function condition(u,t,repeat)
        return  50 .-t      
    end
function affect!(repeat)
        repeat.u[1]=repeat.u[1] +50
    end
callback = DifferentialEquations.ContinuousCallback(condition, affect!)  

#solving
sim=solve(CombinedProblem,Rosenbrock23(),EnsembleSerial(),trajectories=2,callback=callback);
 

# Plotting for ease of understanding example
plot(sim[1].t,sim[1][1,:])
plot!(sim[2].t,sim[2][1,:])
```

I want to produce something like this:

[Example_desired_outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjzYU.png)

But this code produces:

[Example_current_outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qzCc.png)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can make that callback dependent on a parameter and make the parameter different between problems.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisRackauckas! That is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make that callback dependent on a parameter and make the parameter different between problems. For example:

```
function f(du,u,p,t)
  if p == 0
    du[1] = 2u[1]
  else
    du[1] = -2u[1]
  end
  du[2] = -u[2]
end

condition(t,u,integrator) = u[2] - 0.5
affect!(integrator) = integrator.prob.p = 1
```

For more information, check out the FAQ on this topic: https://diffeq.sciml.ai/stable/basics/faq/#Switching-ODE-functions-in-the-middle-of-integration